# Nobody can log into Outlook, Event 1022 error 1010

Tags: exchange-2007

I have taken over a problem regarding Exchange 2007 following the restore of a server from a backup 2 years old.  Nobody can log into Outlook and I can see a ton of errors in the event logs, event ID 1022 on the Exchange server itself.

Any ideas how to fix this?  Google doesn't bring up anything useful apart from checking that the accounts are not disabled or locked - which they aren't.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        MSExchangeIS Mailbox Store
Date:          20/12/2011 15:00:26
Event ID:      1022
Task Category: Logons
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      exchserver.domain
Description:
Logon Failure on database "First Storage Group\Mailbox Database" - Windows account domain\user1; mailbox /o=blahblahblah/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIFDSGDDDFT)/cn=Recipients/cn=user1.
Error: 1010 
Client Machine: computer1.domain 
Client Process: OUTLOOK.EXE 
Client ProcessId: 0 
Client ApplicationId: N/A
```

Comment: Do you mean this was a whole server, bare metal restore from 2 years ago?

Comment: Bare metal restore.  What a mess...  and sorry for the lack of background information to the problem above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a start, this computer will no longer have a trust relationship with the domain due to, well everything. Computer password will have expired, certificates will be wrong and so on. You'd be better rebuilding the server and importing your mailboxes I'd have thought.

Comment: New box, install Exchange in recovery mode, etc etc etc...

Comment: I think you're right with this.  By the time I've got to the bottom of the problems following the restore, I could be halfway there to rebuilding the server from scratch.